# Is it good idea to rotate (remove) firebaseStorageDownloadTokens?

Tags: firebase-storage

My use case is that I want to stream a video which was uploaded to firebase storage.

My understanding is that when the video is first uploaded a `firebaseStorageDownloadToken` is created.

Then whenever in the client app I call `getDownloadUrl` a user gets access to the secret token and can technically share the url with others to watch or download.

I don't really need the long lived access or the videos to be shareable.

Isn't it then more secure to periodically refresh firebaseStorageDownloadTokens with a new value?

That would prevent the stolen urls from working.

And then if a user wants to watch same video again a new url through `getDownloadUrl` is obtained containing a new token.

Do you think it makes sense as a security measure?
What would happen if a `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` is changed while I'm watching the video? Would the stream stop emitting?

Answer (score 2):

While you can definitely revoke the default token, it isn't automatically shared with any users - so the chances of it being abused by them are pretty small. But: users that can upload through the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage can also call `getDownloadURL` on the objects they upload and thus generate new tokens. If this is a significant concern for your use-case, you should probably not allow uploads through the Firebase SDK.

There (currently) is no way in the Firebase SDK to generate a URL that automatically expires. If you want that, consider using one of the Cloud SDKs for Cloud Storage, which have the option to generate so-called [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that do precisely that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want person A to be able to share the url they got from `getDownloadURL` to person B for person B to be able to download the file outside of the app via url they got from `getDownloadURL`. Is it something that enforced App Check can prevent? (BTW: I do not allow file upload)

My another idea was to refresh the tokens on the objects daily just in case they were exposed to unwanted people but that sound like similar concept to signed URL.

I would need a cloud function to get signed URL. Is that correct?

Comment: Download URLs are by definition publicly readable. so once that is generated anyone can use it. You can use App Check to reject requests that don't come from your own app or not from a genuine device. While that will definitely help reduce abuse, it is not a foolproof system.